# Removing a 1970s Schwinn Bottom Bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket, vintage, cruiser, schwinn, threaded-bottom-bracket

I am restoring a 1970 Schwinn Suburban and I am at a loss when it comes to removing this bottom bracket.  The crank arms do not come off normally (no way to use a crank puller) and they won’t unscrew. I have put some lube on the side opposite the drivetrain and maybe I need to wack it with a mallet but any advice would be greatly appreciated!!
[image: drivetrain_side]
[image: kickstand_side]

Answer (score 6):

This is what's called a 'one-piece' or 'Ashtabula' crank.

There is a nut you have removed (or that was already missing) on the threading. Then you remove the left cone via the slot in your second image. Sheldon explains better than I do:
https://www.sheldonbrown.com/opc.html

Comment: Thank you Allen! You responded so fast!

Answer (score 6):

Alan is correct.

Here's a diagram of this type of crank. Sheldon describes it with words but sometimes a picture helps.

[image]

The left side in the picture above is missing both the locknut and the lockwasher.
In an ideal situation you'd have a bottom bracket wrench for one piece cranks
[image]
If you are careful sometimes the adjusting cone can be removed with a screwdriver pushing on one of the slots.
The locknut and adjusting cone are left hand threaded.
Here's a [Park video on this process](https://www.parktool.com/en-us/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-service-one-piece).